# How use active records in Codeigniter for LIKE condition?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How use OR like in Codeigniter?
For example I need:

```
WHERE type LIKE 'test' OR type LIKE 'test2'
```

Comment: You need percent characters in your values... Eg like '%test%' if you want test to appear anywhere in the string.

Comment: I understand, I mean that there is a `$_POST['type'][0] =  test; $_POST['type'][1] =  test2` How to convert it to query string or array?

Comment: If you cannot google it here is for you https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html scroll to like() and or_like()

Comment: I have read it, if use or_like(); and `array('type' => 'test', 'type' => 'test2'); ` it gives me `array('type' => 'test')`

Comment: @FranceDePerost: do you mean your array can be any length?

Comment: You did not read the documents correctly.  The example in the docs is exactly as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28268670/594235).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it would be these:

```
$this->db->like();
$this->db->or_like();
```

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

(Found using [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=codeigniter+or+like)).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use like and or_like both

```
$this->db->like('type', 'test', 'none');
$this->db->or_like('type', 'test2', 'none');
```

will produce

```
WHERE type LIKE 'test' or type LIKE 'test2'
```

See [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) for none,before,after

**Update**
At your example you only matching with 2 key so above solution is OK.
But if you want to match five key like `test1` `test2` `test3` `test4` `test5` you can do it following way

```
    $array=array('test1','test2', 'test3','test4','test5');
    foreach($array as $item)
    {
        $this->db->or_like('type', $item, 'none');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to format array? It can be any array for `or_like()`